# `/var/run/docker.sock` is _sometimes_ owned by `nobody:nogroup` when mounted into a JupyterHub container

Tags: azure, docker

I have performed the following experiment on two Docker hosts, "Host A" and "Host B": pulled a certain JupyterHub image, started it with `/var/run/docker.sock` mounted, then `exec`-ed into the running container and checked the ownership/permissions of `/var/run/docker.sock` inside the container. Details:

```
docker pull jupyterhub/jupyterhub:1.3
docker run -d --name jhub -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jupyterhub/jupyterhub:1.3
docker exec -it jhub /bin/bash
```

Now in the container: `ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`

On "Host A" I get something unexpected:

`srw-rw---- 1 nobody nogroup 0 Jun 24 08:22 /var/run/docker.sock`

whereas on "Host B" I get what I should:

`srw-rw---- 1 root 998 0 May 27 12:30 /var/run/docker.sock`

(note that the GID 998 is the `docker` group ID on the host, so this is OK). It does not matter whether I explicitly mount `/var/run/docker.sock` read-write or read-only.

Both "Host A" and "Host B"...

1. ...run Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS,
2. ...have Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289 installed,
3. ...the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket is owned by `root:docker` on both hosts as it should,
4. ...the JupyterHub image is exactly the same, ID=c9d26511309a,
5. ...the containers' users are `root` so there's no reason to map `docker.sock` to the `nobody:nogroup` user in one of them.

The only difference is that "Host A" is an Azure VM and "Host B" is a physical machine. I set up both and installed Docker on them exactly the same way (or so I think), carefully following the [instructions on the Docker website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

Why this matters? Because I get "Permission denied" errors if I try and spawn a notebook container from the JupyterHub container on "Host A" (the Azure VM). The `DockerSpawner` class needs to access `/var/run/docker.sock` and if it's not owned by `root` it can't perform its job.

Diligent Googling turned up several discussions on having a similar problem in a Jenkins container but the solutions offered usually revolve around adding a user to the `docker` group which does not apply to my case. Help is therefore desperately needed :-) Thanks.

**Update**:

After a complete uninstall/purge and reinstall cycle the problem disappeared, as it so often happens.... :-(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but in my case I found that docker is running "rootless". You can check by `docker info`, under `Security Options` Therefore instead of mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` apparently I need to mount `/run/user/$USERID/docker.sock`

> docker run --rm -it -v /run/user/1118/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker sh

So in your case,

```
docker pull jupyterhub/jupyterhub:1.3
docker run -d --name jhub -v /run/user/"$(id -u)"/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jupyterhub/jupyterhub:1.3
docker exec -it jhub /bin/bash
```